# Get values from php table wordpress

Tags: php, database, wordpress, plugins

In short i want to create a simple php if condition

$varid = 647569;

i want the user_id value  in a $variable so that i can execute a condition of

```
if($varid == $variable){
  //my code
 }
```

but i dont know to get the values of wordpress phpmyadmin table values in a variable form.
Thanks in advance for any suggesions

[image: mydbimage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `get_var` method of [the `$wpdb` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) to write a helper function to test for membership. (This code is untested.)

```
function is_user_a_member($userID){
    global $wpdb;
    $membershipID = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT membership_id FROM jobo_pmpro_memberships_users WHERE user_id=%d",$userID));
    return !empty($membership_id);
}

if( is_user_a_member(get_current_user_id()) ){
    //do your code
}
```

Comment: hey why do you put $userID at the end of the code' what is the use of that?

Comment: In this case, you can make a call to the `is_user_a_member()` function from anywhere in your code. That function accepts a value (hopefully a user ID) and then searches in the `jobo_pmpro_memberships_users` table for a row with a value of userID in the user_id column. (The capitalization could be anything as long as it's consistent.)

Comment: That means you could also call it like this as well: `$varid = 647569; if( is_user_a_member($varid) ){ //do stuff }`